# Checking key included in object

Tags: typescript

I'm having some trouble with TypeScript trying to figure out how to check if an object contains a key, and if so use the value of the key in the object.

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```js
const FRUIT_COLORS = {
  apple: "red",
  orange: "orange",
  banana: "yellow"
};

const VEGETABLE_COLORS = {
  carrot: "orange",
  broccoli: "green",
  asparagus: "green"
};

type Food = keyof typeof FRUIT_COLORS | keyof typeof VEGETABLE_COLORS;

export function color(food: Food) {
  if (food in FRUIT_COLORS) {
    return FRUIT_COLORS[food];
  }

  return VEGETABLE_COLORS[food];
}
```

In this example, ideally, TypeScript would be smart enough to assess that `food` must be `"apple"`, `"orange"` or `"banana"`. However, when I try to access the value (`return FRUIT_COLORS[food];`), I get a type error:

```
typescript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Food' can't be used to index type '{ apple: string; orange: string; banana: string; }'.                                                                                                   
Property 'carrot' does not exist on type '{ apple: string; orange: string; banana: string; }'. [7053]                                 │
```

I also get a similar type error at `return VEGETABLE_COLORS[food];`.

```
typescript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Food' can't be used to index type '{ carrot: string; broccoli: string; asparagus: string; }'.
Property 'orange' does not exist on type '{ carrot: string; broccoli: string; asparagus: string; }'. [7053]
```

Is there a better way to handle this without casting `food` to a more specific type?

Answer (score 2):

You need a user-defined type guard:

```
function isFruitKey(key: Food): key is keyof typeof FRUIT_COLORS {
    return key in FRUIT_COLORS;
}

export function color(food: Food) {
  if (isFruitKey(food)) {
    return FRUIT_COLORS[food]; // food is now type 'keyof typeof FRUIT_COLORS'
  }

  return VEGETABLE_COLORS[food];
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPpkJW)